# How to implement join or relation using JPA CriteriaQuery

Tags: java, jpa, criteriaquery

I have three tables in my database as below :

```
mysql> desc employee;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| empId        | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| empName      | varchar(45)      | NO   |     |         |       |
| jobCode      | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| locationCode | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> desc job;
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| jobCode | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| jobName | varchar(45)      | NO   |     |         |       |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> desc location;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| locationCode | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| locationName | varchar(45)      | NO   |     |         |       |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

And my SQL query is :

```
SELECT e.empName, j.jobName, l.locationName 
FROM employee e, job j, location l 
WHERE e.empId = '101' and e.jobCode = j.jobCode and e.locationCode = l.locationCode;
```

How can I implement this using JPA(Hibernate) CriteriaQuery.

Comment: JPA, JPQL and Criteria do NOT work from database tables; they work from classes and fields. When you've rewritten your post to provide those, then please tell us what you have tried ...

Comment: Please have a look at a Hibernate tutorial, which will point you in the right direction.